# How to end a setInterval whilst using fadeOut & appendTo using images

Tags: jquery

I have a code which I need to stop after it gets to the last image (IMAGE5). At the moment this keeps rotating back to the first image but I want it to effectively count the number of images and stop executing the code after the last image.

Sorry I am not very good with this so baby language would be very useful. Thanks in advance!

```
<center>
<div class="fadein">
<IMG src="IMAGE" width=500/>
<IMG src="IMAGE2" width=500/>
<IMG src="IMAGE3" width=500/>
<IMG src="IMAGE4" width=500/>
<IMG src="IMAGE5" width=500/>

</div>
<script>
    $(function(){
      $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
      setInterval(function(){$('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 6000);    
});
</script>
</center>
```

So now, it would be like this?

```
<div class="fadein">
 <IMG src="IMAGE" width=500/>
<IMG src="IMAGE2" width=500/>
<IMG src="IMAGE3" width=500/>
<IMG src="IMAGE4" width=500/>
<IMG src="IMAGE5" width=500/>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
$('.fadein').find('img').each(function() {
    $(this).fadeIn().delay(6000);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use setInterval for this. If you just want to fade the images in one by one then do the following.

```
$(function() {
    $('.fadein').find('img').each(function() {
        $(this).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

If you want to add a delay between each fadeIn simply add `.delay(6000)` after `.fadeIn()`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have edited above comments-should it look like this? It doesn't seem to work but just shows all images on the same page. Have I done something wrong? Kez

Comment: are the images set to `display: none;` in your css?